# GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1 WHAT IS HAPPENING

Tags: grub2

My computer (Acer Aspire One) that has Ubuntu installed started showing this on boot:

```
GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1 

*Ubuntu 

Advanced Options for Ubuntu 

Memory Test (memtest86+) 

Memory Test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)
```

And I have no idea how to fix it.

Please tell me specifically how to fix it I don't know programming.

Comment: Also, if you want to bypass this menu and boot directly to your OS then, please edit your question. (Do this only if you are NOT dual-booting)

Comment: It's just the bootloader. Oh my god, you really need to act up like that?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong has happened, everything is completely fine, that's just the GRUB menu. Either you press enter now or just wait for 10 secs to boot to your OS.

For better understanding from [GNU:](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/)

> GNU GRUB is a Multiboot boot loader. It was derived from GRUB, the
>   GRand Unified Bootloader, which was originally designed and
>   implemented by Erich Stefan Boleyn.
>
> Briefly, a boot loader is the first software program that runs when a
>   computer starts. It is responsible for loading and transferring
>   control to the operating system kernel software (such as the Hurd or
>   Linux). The kernel, in turn, initializes the rest of the operating
>   system (e.g. GNU).